Anyone else getting this error while setting uṕ webhooks in paypal?
This is the error I am getting:
Error image
This has me concerned because I was previously able to add webhooks to my app and it suddenly stopped working both in sandbox and in live environments.
Any insights?
Here's the error that appears in the console: console errors
The error pops up after I click on the save button in the webhook popup.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
